# Logging out of an account with Firebase auth

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm building an app in Kotlin, Android Studio and Firebase.
My user have a button that have a .setOnClickListener (as I show below) to logout form Firebase. But the app closes when I open the activity/fragment where the button is.

```
logoutButton.setOnClickListener {
    val intent =
        Intent(activity, AccountFragment::class.java)
    Firebase.firebaseAuth.signOut()
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

It isn't giving me any errors on Logcat...at least that I see.
When i change to the fragment that have the button, the app closes and say that the app stopped.

**UPDATE**: there is an error on the Logcat. It says:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

This is an image of the logcat when I changed the fragment:

[Logcat new image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okBSc.png)

Comment: Attach a debugger and detect when you open the activity fragment, go line by line to check for ambiguity or when when you open the fragment screen, the error comes in the logcat but it disappears quickly, so for that you have to scroll the logcat or highlight some text in the logcat and then open the screen and you will catch the error.

Comment: @Hascher7 I already found the error...thanks, but i still don't konw what to do..

Comment: Are you using data binding? And if not, is the logoutButton initialized?

Comment: Are you sure `logoutButton` is initialized?

Comment: @AlexMamo I'm not sure. But I must be doing something wrong, because the button now shows up, but when I click there the app closes...It says that ```java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method Click(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton with id 'bt_logout'```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the button is inside a fragment, then you have place the setOnClickListener code in onViewCreated instead of onCreateView:

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

logoutButton.setOnClickListener {
    val intent =
        Intent(activity, AccountFragment::class.java)
    Firebase.firebaseAuth.signOut()
    startActivity(intent)
}
}
```